# How do I insert Javascript into a web page

Tags: javascript, html

Need help putting this javascript into this HTML code ( i'm new to coding )

```
<img id="coin"/><br/>
<button id="toss">Toss</button><br/>
<div id="count"></div>
```

HTML ^

```
var current = 3;
var elem = document.getElementById('toss');
var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
    if( current > 0 ){
        elem.innerHTML = "<h1>" + current + "</h1>";
    } else {
        if( Math.random() > .5 ){
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://csgowild.com/assets/images/terrorist.png">';
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/4/4c/Csgo_CT_icon_alt.png/revision/latest?cb=20151222191721">';
        }
        clearInterval( intervalId );
    }
    current--;
}, 1000 ); // 1000 ms = 1s
```

Javascript ^

Comment: just write it inside <script type="text/javascript">  your javascript code </script> tags .That's it.

Comment: When you say "Java" that is incorrect. Java and JavaScript are two separate languages, just so there is no confusion.

Comment: @Christian, can you select one of the answers below, if they are too youre liking so we can close this question up? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: to make it work on the click of the button not the following changes:
I added an `onclick' event to your button, and I wrapped the intervalId function in another function. setInterval, the way you had it, fired immediately, now it is associated with the press of the button.

Here you go, just put it in a script tag like so, all in your HTML file:

working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/7cxr3dgf/3/)

```
<img id="coin"/><br/>
<button id="toss" onclick=intervalId();>Toss</button><br/>
<div id="count"></div>
<script>
var current = 3;
var elem = document.getElementById('toss');
var intervalId = function() {setInterval( function(){
    if( current > 0 ){
        elem.innerHTML = "<h1>" + current + "</h1>";
    } else {
        if( Math.random() > .5 ){
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://csgowild.com/assets/images/terrorist.png">';
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = '<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/4/4c/Csgo_CT_icon_alt.png/revision/latest?cb=20151222191721">';
        }
        clearInterval( intervalId );
    }
    current--;
}, 1000 ); // 1000 ms = 1s
}
</script>
```

I think you can take it from here

Welcome to coding, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: haha, no prob man! if you like the answer, mark it correct and if you like you can upvote it too. Good luck out there!
edit, actually you need 15 points to upvote, but you'll have em soon no doubt, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: One question. Is there a way that the person has to press the toss button for it to toss the coin?

Comment: the way you have the code setup now, no. You start that interval right away...you need to make it start on the click of the button...will update the fiddle in a bit

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to include Javascript (or CSS eg.)

**1: Embed it directly into your HTML file**

```
<script>

    // Your code here

</script>
```

This is recommended for small code snippets. If you need much Javascript, possibility number two would make more sense.

**2: Include as own file**

You can also save your Javascript code as - for example - "script.js" and add
the followig to your HTML file:

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Remember to use the correct path.